# die dump laravel strange behavior

Tags: php, laravel

That's is a kind of what I'm used to see in laravel when I use dd($var); function to see whats in the variable:

```
{
id: "1",
username: "Muzikman",
email: "matt.paolini@gmail.com",
password: "$2y$10$Sp7k9Fs0DwFSYHTpWrTWquFmXJpkiKfRIHsjYtdEXTvbdOJwv9AtG",
password_confirmation: "",
confirmation_code: "91f0583ed76c95ebf378648d65d0eac7",
remember_token: "bGmdTchXtilBj41FIazkFS3PDZzr1tVKmTFnMkeeSoD7wpW6hoQ07A42plle",
confirmed: "1",
created_at: "2014-10-19 12:17:55",
updated_at: "2014-10-20 15:07:01",
```

but in my app I have no idea why now I see like this when I dd($var);

```
object(OrdemServico)#728 (23) { ["guarded":protected]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(10) "updated_at" [1]=> string(10) "created_at" [2]=> string(10) "deleted_at" [3]=> string(2) "id" } ["fillable":protected]=> array(13) { [0]=> string(7) "tipo_id" [1]=> string(10) "cliente_id" [2]=> string(11) "contrato_id" [3]=> string(10) "tecnico_id" [4]=> string(10) "created_by" [5]=> string(10) "updated_by" [6]=> string(13) "data_execucao" [7]=> string(13) "tempo_servico" [8]=> string(18) "tempo_deslocamento" [9]=> string(5) "ativo" [10]=> string(10) "finalizada" [11]=> string(5) "os_id" [12]=> string(6) "visita" } ["dates":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "deleted_at" } ["errors"]=> NULL ["originalAttributes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["autoHydrateEntityFromInput"]=> bool(true) ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["table":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["original":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(false) }
```

its all in the same line and hard to read and identify the attributes, how could fix this? 
obs that's isnt the same object, I just got any from google in the first one, the second is my actual dd(); and how show the attributes
thx for help!

Comment: dd() uses var_dump what isn't pretty to look at BUT if you look at the source code oft the page then it looks pretty again

Comment: Seems like laravel added its own de Funktion. But if you want kint then look here http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=15737